# Convert List<List<int>> to double[][]

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to convert from `List<List<int>>` to `double[][]` using LINQ?

I've figured out how to get from `List<List<int>>` to `int[][]` but I'm stuck on the cast.  Here is what I have so far:

```
List<List<int>> ints = new List<List<int>>()
{
    new List<int>(){0, 1, 2},
    new List<int>(){0, 1, 2},
    new List<int>(){0, 1, 2},
};

// int[][]
ints.Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
double[][] doubles = ints.Select(x => x.Select(y => (double)y).ToArray())
                         .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ints.Select(x => x.Select(y => (double)y).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert to double

```
ints.Select(x => x.Select(y => Convert.ToDouble(y)).ToArray()).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ints.Select(x => x.Select(Convert.ToDouble).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: forgot to set it as a code block, <> got scrubbed out as html :(

Comment: Fixed to use Convert.ToDouble, either way the point is that you don't need to write the explicit lambda when you can pass the function.